# django / csvでのデータ書き出しの文字化け&列ずれ対策

Tags: python3, django, csv, array, 文字化け

django, Python共に初心者です。

現在djangoで作ったWebサイト内で表示したタスクリストの書き出しをCSVで対応したいと考えております。
CSVでの書き出しはいけるのですが、これをExcelで開くとutf-8のため、文字化けしてしまいます。
下記のどこかに(推測では　[writer = csv.writer(response)]の部分あたりで文字コードを指定するのかと思っていますが、うまくいきませんでした。

また、それとは別に書き出したデータを見ていると、一部空欄のデータを認識せずエクセルで列ずれが発生しています。

<相談事項>
1.Excelで書き出したCSVデータを開いたときに、文字化けせずに開けるようにする方法をご指導いただきたい
2.DBが空欄だった場合も列を認識し、各項目をそろえて書き出しできる方法をご指導いただきたい

環境
・OS          :    CentOS7
・Python    :    3.6.7
・Django    :    2.1
・DB         ：    MariaDB

お手数ですがアドバイスいただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Task
import csv

def task_export(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename = task_list.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    model = Task
    for task in Task.objects.all().order_by('id').reverse():
        writer.writerow([
            task.id,
            task.pic,
            task.issued_date,
            task.area,
            task.user,
            task.category1,
            task.category2,
            task.category3,
            task.task_content,
            task.details,
            task.duration,
            task.status,
            task.closed_date])
    return response
```

Comment: その列ずれの有無がどうcsvに現れるか、およびそれをExcelに読み込んだ時にどう表示されるか、両方の結果の例を追記してみてはどうでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **1.Excelで書き出したCSVデータを開いたときに、文字化けせずに開けるようにする方法をご指導いただきたい**

に関しては、ファイルの先頭にUTF-8のBOMを書き込めば良いでしょう。
[CSVファイルにUTF-8のBOMをつける - Excelで開くと文字化けするUTF-8のCSVを文字コードを変換せずに開く方法](https://primarytext.jp/blog/1275#CSVUTF-8BOM)

> CSVファイルの文字コードはUTF-8のままで、BOMをつけるだけです。BOMをつけると、ExcelがUTF-8だと判断してくれてShift_JISじゃなくてUTF-8としてCSVを開いてくれます。

Djangoでどのようにすればよいかは、以下の記事が承認回答ありです。
[Return a csv encoded in UTF-8 with BOM from django](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30288666/9014308)

> Add the UTF-8 BOM to the response object before you write your data:
>
> ```
> def render_to_csv(self, request, qs):
>   response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
>   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test.csv"'
>   
>   # BOM
>   response.write("\xEF\xBB\xBF")
>   
>   writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')
>   …
> ```

---

> **2.DBが空欄だった場合も列を認識し、各項目をそろえて書き出しできる方法をご指導いただきたい**

そして上記の質問記事の方に、2.への対策らしき処理が見受けられます。

> ```
> writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')
>
> for row in qs.values_list(*self.fields_to_export):
>   writer.writerow([unicode(v).encode('utf-8') if v is not None else '' for v in row])
> ```

有効な値があれば(Noneでなければ)それを使い、無ければ(Noneなら)空文字列を値とするようです。

```
unicode(v).encode('utf-8') if v is not None else ''
```

これはデータベースの行をそのまま出力するから使える技でしょうか。

質問者さん記事のようにフィールドを選んで(or並び変えて？)出力する場合にどうするかは別として、考え方は使えるのでは？

あるいは、データベースのフィールドの定義を変えられるのなら以下の記事が参考になるかもしれません。
[Djangoモデルフィールドのnullとblankの違いを理解する](https://djangobrothers.com/blogs/django_null_blank/)
[DjangoのModelのFieldのオプション null と blank の違いについて](https://thinkami.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/21/082731)
[differentiate null=True, blank=True in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609192/differentiate-null-true-blank-true-in-django)
[Model field reference | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/)
[Django Modelを使ってみよう](https://eiry.bitbucket.io/tutorials/tutorial/models.html)
[(Django) Allow NULL for certain model filed with blank and null](https://medium.com/@bramblexu/django-allow-null-for-certain-model-filed-with-blank-and-null-b0f402eeca7e)
[Django Tips #8 Blank or Null?](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html)

それから、上記[DjangoのModelのFieldのオプション null と blank の違いについて](https://thinkami.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/21/082731)で、手段はSQLite3のCLIですが、確認のために`NULL`の値を'NULL'という文字列に変えて出力する操作を行っています。

```
# NULLの場合は、"NULL" という文字を出力
# こうしないと、空文字とNULLの違いが分からないため
sqlite> .nullvalue NULL
```

これと同様のことが、個々のフィールドに対してDjangoあるいはMariaDBのプログラム/定義などで指定できるならば、それを使えるのでは？

Comment: >kunifさん
返信遅くなりまして申し訳ありません。
教えていただいた、下記のアドバイスだけで文字化け・列ずれ解決できました。

「CSVファイルの文字コードはUTF-8のままで、BOMをつけるだけです。BOMをつけると、ExcelがUTF-8だと判断してくれてShift_JISじゃなくてUTF-8としてCSVを開いてくれます。

Djangoでどのようにすればよいかは、以下の記事が承認回答ありです。
Return a csv encoded in UTF-8 with BOM from django」

ご丁寧にたくさん教えていただきましてありがとうございました。
まだ勉強不足だと身にしみましたので引き続きがんばりたいと思います。